# Input wont reset after form submission?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, validation

I am using email.js to send emails client side, and validator to validate the email and phone number. Everything works fine, except... I am trying to empty the input fields after a successful submission.

Here is what I have so far:

State management:

```
    const formRef = useRef()
    const [emailError, setEmailError] = useState('')
    const [phoneError, setPhoneError] = useState('')


    const [inputValues, setInputValues] = useState({email: "", phone: ""})
    const handleOnChange = event => {
        const { name, value } = event.target;
        setInputValues({ ...inputValues, [name]: value });
        validateEmail(inputValues.email)
        validatePhone(inputValues.phone)
    };
```

Validation and Submit handler:

```
    const validateEmail = (email) => {
        if (validator.isEmail(email)) {
            setEmailError('Valid Email :)')
            return true
        } else {
            setEmailError('Enter valid Email!')
             return false
        }
       
    }
    const validatePhone = (phone) => {
        if (validator.isMobilePhone(phone)) {
            setPhoneError('Valid Phone :)')
            return true
        } else {
            setPhoneError('Enter valid Phone!')
            return false
        }
    }

    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()

        const isValidEmail = validateEmail(e.target.email.value)
        const isValidPhone = validatePhone(e.target.phone.value)

        if(isValidEmail && isValidPhone){
            console.log("if both inputs are true, on to submit")

            setSentMessage(false)
       
            //shouldnt this line empty out the current fields?
            setInputValues({email: "", phone: ""})
        } else {
            console.log("one of the inputs is false, wont submit")
        }
    }
```

Form:

```
<form ref={formRef} onSubmit={handleSubmit} className={classes.contactPageInputs}>

                <input placeholder='email' type="text" id="userEmail" name="email" onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e)}></input>
                    <span style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'red' }}>{emailError}</span>
                <input placeholder='phone' id="userPhone" name="phone" onChange={(e) => handleOnChange(e)}></input> <br />
                    <span style={{fontWeight: 'bold', color: 'red' }}>{phoneError}</span>
                <button className={classes.submitButton}>submit</button>
</form>
```

**QUESTION:**
How can I reset the input fields after submission?

Comment: *//shouldnt this line empty out the current fields?* - no, because you're only half controlling the inputs. You're providing a change handler, but not providing a value. Since no value is provided, it's technically still an uncontrolled input.

Comment: If you make the changes to provide a value, it will clear like you expect.

Comment: Hey Brian, thank you for the feedback. Could you elaborate on "If you make the changes to provide a value", I dont understand

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/forms.html#controlled-components

Answer (score 0):

Setting the form refs value to null worked.
Here is what I added to the `handleSubmit` function, after sending the email:

```
formRef.current[0].value = null
formRef.current[1].value = null
```

**UPDATE**
This si the better way. I added `value={inputValues.user_email}, value={inputValues.user_phone}, value={inputValues.user_message}`   to each respective input field.

Comment: This is overcomplicating it and making your code error-prone and difficult to maintain. Just read the docs on controlled components that I linked and provide the value to the inputs. You're like 90% there, just finish it out the simple way

Comment: Are you referring to this line? ```value={this.state.value}```

Comment: Yes. Except your value is not stored directly in state so it would need to be modified to be the correct value for the input (`value={inputValues.email}`)

Comment: THE DREAM TEAM RIGHT HERE :D